# Cross platform equivalent of POS for .NET SDK

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform

I like the look of the POS.NET SDK for controlling devices such as cash draw or receipt printers but want something that will also run on a Mac. Does anyone know of a cross platform equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

What about [JavaPOS](http://www.javapos.com/)?